# I am here because I left

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am here because I left,
>
> though most people hate this fact.
>
> When I do what others did,
>
> I don't win praise, not a bit.
>
> When I rest they hate me more,
>
> call me names, not heard before.
>
> I can't stand nor can I lie,
>
> can you tell me who am I?

---

### Solution

I am

> an immigrant.

I am here because I left, though most people hate this fact.

> I am here because I left my home. People in my new home hate me for this decision because they don't like strangers intruding their homes. People in my old home hate me for this decision because they envy me. They wish they could leave their homes as well, like me. They don't wish me the best for my journey, they wish I would stay with them forever in their home without future.

When I do what others did, I don't win praise, not a bit.

> I try to assimilate in my new home, go to work and earn money like everybody else. But they tell me I steal their jobs. I am the reason for their poverty.

When I rest they hate me more, call me names, not heard before.

> But don't I dare to be jobless. They tell me to not be a burden to everyone.

I can't stand nor can I lie, can you tell me who am I?

> So I can't work (stand) and I can't rest (lie [down]). They'll always hate me for who am I.

For this riddle I got inspired by this image:

> [image]

Comment: i've gotten many words to match 2-3 lines... yet can't find one to match them all. the line i'm having trouble with are the 2nd to last one mostly... and the first...

Comment: @thecoder16 I laughed.

Comment: i can't tell if that's a clue or not... :P

Comment: If you feel the need to post a full explanation yourself, post it as a self-answer. The solution is not part of the question and shouldn't be included in the question post. Having said that, it is generally nicer to give a solver some hints and some time to let them come up with the full solution themselves, and/or to annotate their final solution with (e.g.) "**Added by OP**" notes that fill in missing or incorrect details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you:

> An immigrant/refugee?

I am here because I left,

> You're here (as an immigrant) because you left your home

though most people hate this fact.

> There's usually push back on immigration

When I do what others did,

I don't win praise, not a bit.

> The people complaining about immigrants are often only one or two generations from being immigrants themselves

When I rest they hate me more,

> Lots of people label immigrants as lazy

call me names, not heard before.

> Not heard before because you're learning a new language?

I can't stand nor can I lie,

> @YowE3K: "I can't stand" might mean "... for office"
> "nor can I lie" could be a language barrier thing?

Comment: Depending on the country, "I can't stand" might mean "... for office"

Comment: Not bad.  Didn't think of that @YowE3K +1

Comment: Correct answer, but partially correct explanations. I updated my question with the solution. Well done!